# Read LONG RAW with cx_Oracle

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I've a legacy database with LONG RAW columns. Data stored in this columns are about ~100KB.
I'm trying to access those binary data with cx_Oracle.

It is working, however the maximum size I could extract is **~41KB** !

Here's my code (from http://dbaportal.eu/?q=node/147)

```
cursor = db.cursor()    
cursor.arraysize = 1
cursor.setoutputsize(1200000000)

cursor.execute("select data from mytable")
print cursor.description
for row in cursor:
    data = row[0]
    f = open("/tmp/data",'wb')
    f.write(data)
    f.close()
    # Only first line
    break
```

Output is like this:

```
$ python oracle.py
[('GRIB', <type 'cx_Oracle.LONG_BINARY'>, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1)]
$ ls -lh /tmp/data
41186 2011-01-20 12:42 /tmp/pygrib
```

I know `LONG RAW` are not easy to deal with. Some methods tell to recreate a new table with `BLOB` column. But I can't afford it because I've already gigas of data in this format...

Any idea?

Comment: me curious - why this `cursor.setoutputsize(1200000000)`? I see it's a different in your linked code.

Comment: It was not working with default value, so I tried to increase it ...

Comment: Have you looked into converting to a `blob` on the fly with `dbms_lob`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global temporary table with a `BLOB` column, and then just before getting the `LONG RAW` value insert it into this table using `TO_LOB` conversion function. Then you can select the `BLOB` value from the temporary table.